# How to pass a list to R in rpy2 and get result back

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to use rpy2 for the first time.  Let's say I have in python a list

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to do call in R

```
ks.test(l, pexp)
```

How can I do that?

My initial try is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

l = [1,2,3,4,5]

f = robjects.r('''
f<-function(l){
    ks.test(l, pexp)
}''')
print f(l)
```

This clearly isn't the right way to do it as I get

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rpy2-test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print f(l)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 166, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 99, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a python list to R directly. You can convert to a R int vector before use it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

l = [1,2,3,4,5]

# get ks.test via execute string as R statement
test = robjects.r('ks.test')
# get a built-in functions variables directly
pexp = robjects.r.pexp

l_vector = robjects.IntVector(l)
result = test(l_vector, pexp)
print result[result.names.index('p.value')]
```

Reference:

- [Working with R’s OOPs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/robjects_oop.html)
- [Functions](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/robjects_functions.html)
- [Vectors and arrays](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/vector.html#assigning-python-style)

Comment: Thanks very much!  Is there a more compact way of calling ks.test without having to define a new function f?

Comment: @user2179021 I have revisited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again. If I just want the p-value, do I have to extract it in R ? I ask as it seems that python just gets a string back.

Comment: @user2179021 The returned value is a ListVector, not a data frame as I expect. I don't know why. However, you can get p.value via `result[result.names.index('p.value')]`.

Comment: `result[result.names.index('p.value')][0]` seems to be the actual value I wanted. Thanks!