# Convert Python list and store it in R environment. So I can access the list using rpy2.objects.r()

Tags: r, python-3.x, rstudio, rpy2

Let's say I have a list in Python.

```
a_list = list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

I want to store `a_list` in R environment as `R_a_list`. So i can use R functions to apply on a_list using rpy2.robjects like following:

```
rpy2.robjects('''length(R_a_list)''')
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a list to R in rpy2 and get result back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269655/how-to-pass-a-list-to-r-in-rpy2-and-get-result-back)

Comment: Did you check the documentation ? (for example, about environments: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_environments.html#environments)